# Are there online cryptowallets where I can upload my wallet.dat to get my balance?

Tags: wallet, wallet.dat, balance

I have some `wallet.dat` files from the time I was fiddling with cryptocurrencies years ago.

Tried to open them using the wallet clients of each one, they load, but I have to download (and process?) the whole blockchain to know the actual balance, and it's taking a lot of time and disk space.

Are there any online services that already have the blockchain so I just load my `wallet.dat` to get my balance?

I know there are security risks about giving my `wallet.dat`, my idea is to then transfer the wallet balance to another online wallet like coinbase.

Any advice is welcome since I'm out of the loop.